# Jquery passing value dynamically to animate method

Tags: jquery-animate

If I'm trying to pass Transition_Time value dynamically animate method not caring this value. If I'm using hard code value directly animate is working properly.

```
Not working:
var Transition_Time=5000;
     $('#slides ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, Transition_Time, function () {
                });
---------------------------
working:
 $('#slides ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, 5000, function () {
                });


Any help?

Thanks,
vijay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm adding *1, it is working.

$('#slides ul').animate({ 'left': left_indent }, Transition_Time*1, function () {
}

-Vijay